# How can I bulk insert concatenated list into sql database in Python?

Tags: python

So I have a loop that concatenates lists of files that I need to send to the database. The columns might be different on each concatenated list. I've used `to_sql` method, but considering it's a lot of data, it takes too much time. I've done a lot of tests using different `chunksizes`, `fast_executemany`, etc, but I think the problem is really about using `to_sql`, it's just too slow...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using `method='multi'` ?

Comment: fast_executemany is multi-inserted by default, so there's no need for specify the method.

Comment: Yes, I've used fast_executemany and method='multi'. And for 50MB of data, it takes more than half an hour... I've wondered if there was some multiprocessing or parallelism solution to distribute the workload and make it faster?